# How to know when the timeStamp changes?

Tags: java, logic

I have this class `Log`:

```
private Integer id;

private Timestamp time;

private String value;
```

I want to generate reports about the average in these intervals: `seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years`.
For instance, I have these values in a `List<Log> logs`:

code:

```
for (Log log : logs)
            System.out.println(log.getTime().toString() + " " + log.getValue() + ", ");
```

output:

```
INFO: 2012-04-26 20:06:21.0 10.0, 
INFO: 2012-04-27 09:09:32.0 10.0, 
INFO: 2012-04-27 09:31:09.0 15.0, 
INFO: 2012-04-27 09:31:23.0 27.0, 
INFO: 2012-04-27 09:31:42.0 30.0, 
INFO: 2012-04-27 09:31:54.0 47.0, 
INFO: 2012-04-27 12:19:00.0 80.0,
```

And I want to take the average in `minutes`, then the results should be:

```
10 / 1 = 10, 
10 / 1 = 10, 
15 + 27 + 30 + 47 = 119/4 = 29.75
80 / 1 = 80
```

Do you guys have any idea how I could do this ?

Comment: Loop over every log item, if it has the same minute value then add it to a running total inside a map, also keep a separate list of the counts for each minute. Then loop again and print the total/count

Comment: And can I suggest you use JodaTime instead of (what I assume is) java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: @BeRecursive the problem is this, how did I now that they are different ? Could you show me some example ?

Comment: What do you mean that they are different? Surely you just loop over the logs and sum them in a map where the key is the minute

Comment: how do I use the JodaTime with TimeStamp, as you suggest ?

Comment: I still don't knowing what to do here guys.

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about something like this (though I threw this together quickly when I saw you were still struggling - the use of the map to keep count isn't brilliant):

Change Log to:

```
Integer id;
DateTime time;
String value;

public Log(Integer id, Timestamp time, String value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.time = new DateTime(time.getTime());
    this.value = value;
}
```

Then:

```
// Build some fake logs
final List<Log> logs = new ArrayList<Log>();
logs.add(new Log(1, new Timestamp(new DateTime().withDate(2011,1,1).getMillis()), "90"));
logs.add(new Log(1, new Timestamp(new DateTime().withDate(2010,1,1).withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis()), "60"));
logs.add(new Log(1, new Timestamp(new DateTime().withDate(2010,1,1).withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis()), "80"));
logs.add(new Log(1, new Timestamp(new DateTime().withDate(2009,1,1).getMillis()), "70"));
final Map<DateTime, Integer> total = new HashMap<DateTime, Integer>();
final Map<DateTime, Integer> count = new HashMap<DateTime, Integer>();

for(Log l : logs) {
    // Round down to the nearest minute
    final DateTime t = l.getTime().withSecondOfMinute(0);
    Integer sum = total.get(t);
    sum = (sum == null) ? 0 : sum;
    total.put(t, sum + Integer.parseInt(l.getValue()));

    Integer c = count.get(t);
    c = (c == null) ? 0 : c;
    count.put(t, c + 1);
}

for(Map.Entry<DateTime, Integer> entry : total.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getValue() / count.get(entry.getKey()));
}
```

Here I assume you will still want to use `TimeStamp` in the `Log` constructor but don't mind storing it internally as a JodaTime `DateTime` object. Then we create some fake logs. We then loop over all the logs and store to the nearest minute both the count and the total. Realistically I would create an object to store this data (both total and count) and then use the `DateTime` as the key. I hope this makes sense.